# How to create and apply rotation matrix to vector

Tags: c, vector, raytracing, rotational-matrices

I'am creating my first ray tracing program in C and I'am currently trying to rotate the camera. Basically , change the direction of the ray origin.

I already have a ray direction, which is a vector and I want to apply a rotation matrix to this Vector.

```c
void    render(void)
{
    t_Color     color;
    int         x;
    int         y;
    t_Vector    d;

    x = ((canvas()->width / 2) * -1);
    y = (canvas()->height / 2);
    while (--y >= (canvas()->height / 2) * -1)
    {
        while (++x <= (canvas()->width / 2))
        {
            d = canvas_to_viewport(x, y);
            color = trace_ray(d, 1, INT_MAX);
            put_pixel(x, y, color);
        }
        x = ((canvas()->width / 2) * -1);
    }
}
```

What I want to do is basically, change this line :

```
// d represents the ray direction

d = canvas_to_viewport(x, y);
```

to

```
// d represents the ray direction after rotating

d = rotation_matrix * canvas_to_viewport(x, y);
```

My program will receive some input in the form of :

```
3d normalized orientation vector. In range [-1,1] for each x,y,z axis:
0.0,  0.0,  1.0
```

Those coordinates should indicate the orientation for my camera. I must admit linear algebra is not my strongest point, so I would like to know how can I convert those orientation coordinates into a rotation matrix and how to multiply it by a vector to get another vector , hopefully, indicating the new direction.

Comment: I don't understand your code. Objects, such as cameras, in 3D space normally have position and orientation coordinate, that's 6 values. A transformation matrix is a matrix of orthogonal normal vectors, which can change the orientation of the object. The main other way to do it is with quaternions, but they are difficult to get your head around. I don't see where are your camera's position and orientation?